# How to use the SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm new to Symfony and I'm trying to create a database interface using Sonata and Doctrine ORM. At first, I`ve read [this tutorial](http://tech.dupeu.pl/2012/10/getting-started-with-symfony-2-1-fosuserbundle-sonatauserbundle-and-sonataadminbundle/) and after a few days it all start working on my VirtualBox machine Ubuntu server.

Now, I`m trying to use the sonata admin in another bundle.

So, I`ve got my SonataAdminBundle here:

```
/var/www/Symfony/testsonata/src/Application/Sonata
```

And new bundle here:

```
/var/www/Symfony/testsonata/src/Application/MyDbBundle
```

I`m trying to use [this man](http://symfonydev.ru/symfony-back-and-front-interfaces/) (it`s on russian).

Next, after I`ve got working Sonata, I`m created a new bundle:

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Application/MyDbBundle

You are going to generate a "Application\MyDbBundle\MyDbBundle" bundle
in "/var/www/Symfony/testsonata/src/" using the "annotation" format.
```

Then, I ran the following commands:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyDbBundle xml --filter=Link
writing /var/www/Symfony/testsonata/src/Application/MyDbBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Link.orm.xml

$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities --path="/var/www/Symfony/testsonata/src" MyDbBundle:Link

Generating entities for namespace "Application\MyDbBundle\Entity\Link"
  > backing up Link.php to Link.php~
  > generating Application\MyDbBundle\Entity\Link
```

And the last thing I was trying to do, is to create an Administrative class and a Service description

I have created this file `/var/www/Symfony/testsonata/src/Application/MyDbBundle/Admin/LinkAdmin.php` which contains:

```php
<?php
namespace Application\MyDbBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;
use My\DbBundle\Entity\Link;

class LinkAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('title')
                      ->add('url');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('title')
                   ->add('url')
                   ->add('updatedAt');
    } 

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('title')
                   ->add('url')
                   ->add('annotation');
    }
}
```

And I added this to my `services.xml`:

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
      <service id="sonata.admin.my.db.link" class="Application\MyDbBundle\Admin\LinkAdmin">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Databases" label="Links"/>
            <argument/>
            <argument>Application\MyDbBundle\Entity\Link</argument>
            <argument>SonataAdminBundle:CRUD</argument>
        </service>
    </services> 
</container>
```

When I go to

```
http://localhost/Symfony/testsonata/web/app_dev.php/admin/dashboard
```

I get this message:

> InvalidArgumentException: [ERROR 94] Validation failed: no DTD found ! (in n/a - line 5, column 20)
>   [ERROR 5] Extra content at the end of the document (in n/a - line 22, column 1)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, something went wrong with your xml config file. Why is there an `<argument/>` at the begining? It might be the problem.

PS: I mean, does this `<argument></argument>` works better?

Comment: yes, i don`t noticed this. deleted it <argument/>, and changed this 
    use My\DbBundle\Entity\Link;
to
    use Application\MyDbBundle\Entity\Link;
 but nothing changes.

maybe something wrong then symfony tryed to load sonata.admin.my.db.link ? or something wrong with the paths.. but i didn`t see mistakes

Comment: Where did you found the `<container>` line? If i'm not wrong, the DTD is defined here. Is using xml an obligation? I found more resources in yaml format. Try adding this `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>`

Comment: http://symfonydev.ru/symfony-back-and-front-interfaces/
from this manual.

    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
this doesn`t make any effect

Comment: Try to put in your file only the `<service></service>` and it's children since the doc seems to say so. 
If you try to access both of the url starting by symfony.com, the website returns a 404 error which explains the no DTD found. You can also try to remove those links from your container tag.

Comment: then it`s looks like this

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <services>
      <service id="sonata.admin.my.db.link" class="Application\MyDbBundle\Admin\LinkAdmin">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Базы данных" label="Ссылки"/>
            <argument>Application\MyDbBundle\Entity\Link</argument>
            <argument>SonataAdminBundle:CRUD</argument>
        </service>
    </services>

Comment: and the error is
InvalidArgumentException: [ERROR 1845] Element 'services': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (in /var/www/Symfony/testsonata/web/ - line 2, column 0)

Comment: Is there a stack trace below the error? Are you sure that this is the file that cause the problem? Because it says "extra content at line 22", but there are only 12 lines.

Comment: And also, are you using it locally or on a web server? Because php DOM needs to access internet to retrieve the DTD. Some people say that it might be a hosting problem.

Comment: I`m not sure what the problem is in this file, but it happens when i try to change this file. any possibilities? i use it on the local apache2+mysql servers

Comment: With or without internet access? Can you try to use the yaml example? Just to see if the problem come from the config or something else.

Comment: With or without internet access? - both variants. which yaml example do u mean?

Comment: This one `services:
   sonata.news.admin.post:
      class: Sonata\NewsBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: sonata_blog, label: post }
      arguments: [null, Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post, SonataNewsBundle:PostAdmin]` Of course set it to match your paths. Found at the bottom of http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/architecture.html Ps: look at the link to find the space indention because it matters in yaml.

Comment: Just saw that there is a xml example just above the yaml one. They only put `<service></service>` no `<conatiner>` or `<services>`.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe i need to make another paths? because MyDbBundle and Sonata is in the different directories

Comment: I don't think that's it. My project has a bundle in src/ and sonata in vendor/